# Setting the default resource for an app in Glassfish

Tags: glassfish

How do I set the default resource for an app in Glassfish? For example, if I type:

```
http://localhost/MyApp/
```

I would like it to use the resource xyz.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `welcome-file` property in your [web.xml](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#The_Welcome_File_List) file

```
<welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>xyz.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: I actually have that but it doesn't do anything. Anything I need to get that to work?